# What's the difference between flag messages and toast messages?

Tags: notification, toast

What's the difference between flag messages and toast messages? Are they the same thing?

Comment: Where are these terms used? Who uses them? Do you have example images of them?

Comment: I haven’t heard flag notification before. Here is a question about toasts: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11998/what-is-a-toast-notification